# wrap some functionality into function inside a private method

Tags: javascript

I have a class-constructor with two private methods:

```
var deleteOption = function(){...};
var removeOption = function(){...};
```

The first one after doing some operations removes HTML element from the DOM by calling `removeOption()` method. This is the only place where this method is called. I thought today that maybe it would be a good idea to remove that method from private interface and put inside  `deleteOption` method as function:

```
var deleteOption = function(){
    ... //do some operations here

    removeOption();
    function removeOption() {
        ...
    }
};
```

`1) Is it a common practice in JavaScript?`

`2) Is it a good desicions from the standpoint of class architecture?`

Answer (score 1):

If you are to only call it in that function, and not passing an array of elements at all (e.g. no loops) you might as well implement only the functions code rather than the entire function, If removeOption is quite large, comment it as needed as well.

Putting functions inside functions is a commonly used method inside JavaScript but not always usefull. To me it seems you just called another external function that will only execute in one other function, so the best you could do is simply merge those functions.

The profit is that you'll have one function less to call because the code is already in the native function, therefore it will be slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks, but by doing this _best you could do is simply merge those functions_, I will loose methods' cohesion. This is why the method ` removeOption` was designed in the first place, to adhere to Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Hmmn,.. I guessed so, I do still think merging them would slightly speed up the process tho, however In this particular case it would not really matter except for there being an extra function, which is no issue at all. I'd say do what your gut tells you here.

Comment: :)... my concern isn't speed at the moment. The application got so big that I hardly understand what's going on. So I started to look for best practices. Found a good account for them in what I believe is best book about software design - Code Complete - but there is nothing like that for JS :(.

Comment: There are few good books about JS, personally I think that SO and YT will be far greater resources for learning these days, however I hope to have helped you make a descision on what you plan to do (if so don't forget to upvote / accept) - Sid

Comment: Thanks alot, maybe someone else will still come along to give you the deep details on optimalisation here, good luck!